# Display gridview row count based on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am using this code to take a gridview count and display in a label on page load and works fine.

**Page Load:**

```
int rowCount = dtDetails.Rows.Count;
lblTotalRows.Text = rowCount.ToString() + "records found";
```

I have a dropdown above my gridview and when I select dropdown values the row count have to changed based on the dropdown selected values.

How could I possibly do that in dropdown selected index change

```
protected void ddlGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtGroup = DataRepository.GetGroup(ddlGroup.Text);
    gvDetails.DataSource = dtGroup;
    gvDetails.DataBind();
   //Now how could I possible show the respective row counts in the label
}

protected void ddlGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtDept = DataRepository.GetDept(ddlGroup.Text, ddlDept.Text);
    gvDetails.DataSource = dtDept;
    gvDetails.DataBind();
   //Now how could I possible show the respective row counts of both group and 
     dept row count  since they are cascading dropdowns in the label
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to make a SetData() method so all this kind of code is in one place. So in this instance I would:

```
protected void SetData(DataTable dtGroup)
{
    // Bind the data to the grid
    gvDetails.DataSource = dtGroup;
    gvODetails.DataBind();

    // Show row count
    if (!dtGroup.Rows.Count.Equals(0))
        lblTotalRows.Text = dtGroup.Rows.Count + " records found";
    else
        lblTotalRows.Text = "No records found";
 }
```

This way you only have one place that does all the 'bindind' so in your Page_Load you can just call this SetData() method and pass in the datatable, and the same on your SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: I have nearly 6 dropdowns in my page of 2 sets and they are cascading dropdowns. Will this fit that scenario because I see you pass a datatable for one dropdown in the argument.